# Some outlets non working on same circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

In my kitchen I have the following issue:

- Spontaneously, some of the wall outlets did no longer work.
- Others however continued to be working.
- After some time, all outlets worked again.

I know that I have a single fuse for all those outlets in that room. That fuse also covers the light, and two additional rooms with both lights and outlets.  There were no change in connected devices or similar, and all devices are rather "low power" or were off during that time (the most high power would be a microwave, but as I said, it was off/standby).

I know that the wiring in that room runs as depicted in the following graphic:

[image: Schematic]

Location: Germany, Europe. The house is not too old (1996 AFAIK) and therefore I'm very sure that the wiring runs as depicted (that is in straight lines, 90° corners) - everything else would be against local building codes AFAIK. The wiring has 3 wires: neutral, ground and hot. 230V~ 50Hz.

The last outlet which was still working is behind wall mounted kitchen shelves.  The drilled holes for these shelves are not close to any wiring (more than 40cm away). Also these shelves are there since 3 years, so no recent changes.

I've already opened (after breaking the circuit of course) the first of the non-working outlets, and checked all connections - initially assuming a loose connection.

**Is there any other possibility for the issues I've been seeing other than a loose connection on either the last working or first non-working outlet?**

Removing the wall mounted shelves will be a lot of effort, so if there's any other possible failure case I'd like to investigate that first.

Answer (score 1):

No - other than a break in the line which is unlikely.
I'm assuming the red outlets are not working. If you checked the line coming into the first non-working outlet and found no power and the outlet behind the shelves works - the problem then has to be between the last working outlet (behind the shelf) and the first non-working one.
Afraid you're going to have to bite the bullet with the shelves. I'm not up on code in Germany but I think that outlet behind the shelves should be accessible.